# Как поменять ход в крестики-нолики на JS

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в JS, пришло время написать мини-проект. Но не могу понять, почему мой код не работает. Я хочу, чтоб на четном ходе появлялись крестики, а на нечетном - нолики (я так думала решить), но в итоге при таком коде у меня в ячейках проставляются лишь крестики, а нолики игнорируются. Что я делаю не так?

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.game-field_cell'); 

for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', changeTurns, {once: true});
} // навесила событие на все выбранные ячейки

let step = 0;
function changeTurns () {
   if (step % 2 === 0) {
   this.innerHTML = 'X';
  } else {
   this.innerHTML = 'O';
  } 
} // хотела написать функцию, которая будет менять ход крестиков и ноликов, но в итоге в ячейках выводятся только крестики
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо увеличивать счетчик при каждом вызове функции

```
let step = 0;
function changeTurns () {
  if (step % 2 === 0) {
    this.innerHTML = 'X';
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'O';
  } 
  step++; // Увеличиваем счетчик
}
```

Так же можно сократить функцию

```
function changeTurns () {
  this.innerHTML = step++ % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Когда буду рефакторить, обязательно воспользуюсь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы нигде не прибавляете значение `step` и оно у вас всегда равно нулю